# Decrease white space above and below plot_grid in RMarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I'm trying to plot 3 images next to one another, with a single border around them, but my current code outputs too much white space above and below when knitting to pdf:

[image]

I use NULL in my plot_grid for easy padding on the sides, but I really want to remove the whitespace above and below:

```
{r, echo=F, cache=T, fig.cap=fig_cap("ch7__peaches.example__fig.cap"), out.width="100%"}

    peach1 <- ggdraw() + draw_image("./resources/images/peach1-photo-grey.png")
    peach2 <- ggdraw() + draw_image("./resources/images/peach2-photo-grey.png")
    peach3 <- ggdraw() + draw_image("./resources/images/peach3-photo-grey.png")
    
    plot_grid(NULL, peach1, NULL, peach2, NULL, peach3, NULL, ncol = 7, rel_widths = c(0.3, 1, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 1, 0.3)) + 
        theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1), legend.title = element_blank())
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is so interesting (but i think, that a *bug* is guilty in this behavior, hah), when we place several images in a row (`nrow`)- we see a bearable white space.

But we can use function `include_graphics` from **knitr** library.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="caption",fig.show='hold', fig.align='center'}
knitr::include_graphics(c("xxx.png","xxx.png", "xxx.png")) 
```
````

... with out.width and out.height you can tune your output.

[image]

**Adding:** The simpliest LaTeX-solution:

```
#add to your header
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{graphicx}
```

---

```
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\fbox {\includegraphics{xxx.png}\hspace{0.1in}\includegraphics{xxx.png}\hspace{0.1in}\includegraphics{xxx.png}}
\caption{This is that what you want}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Sort of..this is definitely better in terms of white space above and below, but I lose the border.

Comment: @adajam Yes, border.  Need to think. hmmm

Comment: @adajam Look, i made something new for you. If i helped to you - you can accept my answer, putting a tick. Thanks ;)